# Get controller name from Module.php

Tags: zend-framework2

I already managed to subscribe to the `onDispatch()` method in my `Application\Module.php` where more routing information should be available than `onBootstrap()`.

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    $em = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager(); 
    $em->attach(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'onDispatch'));
}

public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e) {
    //$controllerName = /* ... ? */;
    $e->getViewModel()->setVariables(
        array('controllerName'=> $controllerName,
        'actionName' => $actionName)
    );
return parent::onDispatch($e);
```

What would I need to call to the the controller name? And I mean not the class, but say, if my controller class if `Application\Controller\MyController`, I would like to receive `my-controller` as what would be found in the URL. I also would not like to do string matching on the URL itself as I do not want to rely on it due to possible more complex routing.

Also, if you know, please tell me how I can also get the action name as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.
The answer is similar to what Bram Gerritsen said.

The thing is, the original `controller` parameter gets overridden by having the namespace prepended, capitalizing the controller name, dash separating what was camel case and such. This can be found in `\Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener` near the end of the `onRoute()` method.

As can be seen, the original controller parameter gets saved under the `__CONTROLLER__` parameter, or using constants `\Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener::ORIGINAL_CONTROLLER`.

So in the end, if my current controller is `\Application\Controller\MyControllerController` and I wish to retrieve the original controller parameter (like `my-controller`, not `Application\Controller\MyController`), I need to call this:

```
public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e)
{
    $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
    $controllerParamName = \Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener::ORIGINAL_CONTROLLER;
    $controller = $routeMatch->getParam($controllerParamName); // my-controller
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get that information from the routematch which is available in the MvcEvent in the dispatch listener.

```
public function onDispatch(\Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent $e)
{
    $routeMatch = $e->getRouteMatch();
    $controller = $routeMatch->getParam('controller');
    $action = $routeMatch->getParam('action');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for retrieving the controller name in the form that it would be taken from the url with the default application route that comes with the Zend Skeleton Application. So your bit of code would give me the default controller as `Application\Controller\Index`. I would like to receive it as `index`. The same way it would be extracted for the url, and the same was I can pass it to any url building helper as the controller parameter.